# How can I get the img src from this page with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to get some data from this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mango_cultivars

[img src that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk0TX.png)

I can get everything that I need except the img src with this code

```
const recordList = await page.$$eval(
      'div#mw-content-text > div.mw-parser-output > table > tbody > tr',
      (trows) => {
         let rowList = []
         trows.forEach((row) => {
            let record = { name: '', image: '', origin: '', notes: '' }

            record.image = row.querySelector('a > img').src

            const tdList = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('td'), (column) => column.innerText) 
            const imageSrc = row.querySelectorAll('a > img').getAttribute('src')
            

            record.name = tdList[0] 
            record.origin = tdList[2]
            record.notes = tdList[3]
            rowList.push(record)
         })

         return rowList
      }
   )
```

The error I am getting: `Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'src')`

Comment: If you look at the table, clearly many rows don't have images. So you should check whether the `querySelector` call returned null, which indicates that there was no image for that row, and handle it as you please if it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your record.image line in a conditional like this

```js
if(row.querySelector('a > img')){
    record.image = row.querySelector('a > img').src
}
```

This will ask if an img inside of an a tag exists, and if it does, then add it to the object.